# How to create full width banner with text on it that start from where the bootstrap container starts?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am working on a personal website where I need to implement a banner having text on it just like that I am stuck in making the image take full width and make the text start from where the bootstrap container start and on resize I want the text to take one full row and image take a complete row below it. Attached is the reference image and code what I have done so far. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
you can download the image from here
https://ibb.co/0m9pXS2

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    body {
      column-gap: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .hero-image {
      background-image: url("image-url-here");
      height: 450px;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #f5f5f5">
        <div class="container">
          <h1>lorem ipsum dollar ismat</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Voluptatibus, quaerat architecto distinctio nam debitis a
            consectetur iusto. Ea temporibus praesentium sint quibusdam mollitia
            fugiat aliquam numquam inventore, dignissimos libero? Obcaecati.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 hero-image"></div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you check the bootstrap website for `jumbotron` components from there you can simply add a background here's a crude example https://jsfiddle.net/05k4v1s6/

Answer (score 0):

I have use Flex Property:-

```css
body 
{
    column-gap: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


.container{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    height:50vh;
    width:100%;
}

p{
    width:60%;
    line-height:2;
}

.content{
    padding: 40px 50px 2px 50px;
}

.hero-img{
    width:80%;
    margin-left: 8rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1200px) 
{
    .container{
        display: block;
        height: 70vh;
    }
    .content{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    p{
        font-size: 2rem;
        width: auto;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>


    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis voluptas dolores nulla! Quasi cumque numquam, tenetur hic
                 laboriosam, eveniet, necessitatibus enim quae cupiditate dicta harum consectetur corrupti debitis totam fugiat.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="hero-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/RY6GSmb/team-banner.png" alt="">

        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```